# Undefined control sequence. \end{align*}

Tags: errors, amsmath

```
\begin{align*}
    \DIV \BP =&~\Bzero~,\label{PDE1}\\
    \rho_0 c \dot{\theta}=&-\DIV \BQ + \theta\p{\theta}\BP:\dot{\BF}~.\label{PDE2}
\end{align*}
```

I had used packages like `amsmath`,`amsfonts`,`amssymb`... But it's showing the following error:

```
Undefined control sequence. \end{align*}
```

Do I need to add other packages?

Comment: What are `\DIV`, `\BP`, `\BQ` and `\BF` commands?

Comment: Actually it's an equation Div P = 0
Div= divergent. Do I need to add anymore packages to access those unrecognised sentence?

Comment: Did you define them as new operators or macro or whatelse?

Comment: welcome to tex.se! please provide small but vomplete document beginning with `\documentclass{...}, with used to math related packages and your definitiones in preamble,  and ending with `\end{document}`. now we can only guessing are you defined somewhere used commands ...

Comment: Do we have any packages named hd.sty? I think it's the problem. My align works perfectly fine if I comment out all the equations. So I think the \DIV ,\BP has to do something. I just copied this equation from another tex file of which my professor gave me. SO any guesses of which file would I be missing?. Or how to create a command like that or is it some kind of macro?

Comment: @AKTomThomas: What are you referring to when you say "create a command like that"? Instead, we'd like to replicate your problematic behaviour, so if you would be so kind as to provide the community with a minimal example that we can copy-and-paste-and-compile, we'll be glad to help.

Answer (score 4):

"Undefined control sequence. \end{align*}"
"Undefined control sequence. \end{align}"
or the like means that somewhere between
\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}
you have a macro that has not been defined.

Make a copy of that "\begin{align*} ... \end{align*}" part
and edit it to a "\begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}".
Then compile again: now you will get an error message referring to the missing macro.

For example, if you then get: "Undefined control sequence. ...3a^b+\sin\theta\exp(-i2\pi m\Bzero",
then the last macro in that string, in this case "\Bzero", is the undefined macro.
Fix that and try again until you have no errors.

(How to define a macro? Maybe the macro is defined by using some package; e.g., \usepackage{amsmath} defines some macros. Or maybe you wanted to define the macro yourself by "\newcommand{\Bzero}..." but forgot. Or maybe you copied some code from somewhere but forgot to copy the part where the macro \Bzero was defined.)

When you have no errors, you can remove the additional \begin{equation*} ... \end{equation*}

Answer (score 3):

Well, assuming that you defined some commands somewhere in your document, I took the liberty to define them too to be able to compile your document.

The problems were:

1. All the user-undefined commands. I created them but you'll have to change to the correct ones later.
2. The `align*` environment produces an unnumbered equation, so you cannot put labels in it (unless you have a `\tag` on that same line, as barbara beeton says).

After some modifications, here is your code, with only the `amsmath` package and your mysterious user-defined commands.

I also added another version where you can put labels on your equations.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\DIV}{\div}
\newcommand{\BP}{\left<BP\right>}
\newcommand{\Bzero}{\left<Bzero\right>}
\newcommand{\BQ}{\left<BQ\right>}
\newcommand{\p}{\left<p\right>}
\newcommand{\BF}{\left<BF\right>}

\begin{align*}
    \DIV \BP & = \Bzero~,\\
    \rho_0 c \dot{\theta} & = -\DIV \BQ + \theta\p{\theta}\BP:\dot{\BF}~.
\end{align*}

\begin{subequations}
 \begin{align}
    \DIV \BP & = \Bzero~,\label{PDE1}\\
    \rho_0 c \dot{\theta} & = -\DIV \BQ + \theta\p{\theta}\BP:\dot{\BF}~.\label{PDE2}
 \end{align}
\end{subequations}

See Eqs. \ref{PDE1} and \ref{PDE2}

\end{document}
```

Comment: a couple of things.  `\label` *can* be used with `align*` if `\tag` is used on the same line.  and the `&` is better used *before* the signs of relation, otherwise `={}&` and omit the `~`.  the spacing should be provided automatically by inbuilt rules.

Comment: I didn't know about `\tag`. Thanks @barbarabeeton!

Answer (score 0):

I came across this same error. I do not have the back-end knowledge to explain why it happens. But the way out is to move the
`\usepackage{amsmath}`

before whatever user-defined commands like,

`\def\logoname{LOGO-generic-web}`
are being defined.

So,

```
`\def\logoname{LOGO-generic-web}`
`\usepackage{amsmath}`
```

gives error.

If you once compile with

```
`\usepackage{amsmath}` 
`\def\logoname{LOGO-generic-web}`
```

it no longer gives error for `\end{align}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!